# Xcode 8 SpriteKit: GameScene.swift file not being recognized/ran

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift3, xcode8

Alright, so I've had this issue before and have looked everywhere for answers. There are similar questions on here, one being this exactly, but with no answer and it seems to have been abandoned.

The issue is that all the code in my GameScene.swift seems to have no effect on what's being ran in my project. Everything that I built using the interface builder on my GameScene.sks file appears just as it is supposed to, but changes in labels, impulses or other changes to objects that I've put in my .swift file seem to be ignored.

To test this, I went into my didMovetoview section of my GameScene.swift and simply put a: print("hello"), to see if it would run in the console and that there were other issues, but it completely ignored it. I have also created a label on the .sks interface builder and used the .swift file to change the text, which also didn't affect it at all.

I have made sure that the class name "GameScene" that is in the .swift file is also the correct custom class that's referenced in the .sks file. I've made sure the GameViewController is my initial view controller and that it sets the scene to the correct GameScene.sks.

After doing some research, I have done things such as copying the GameScene.swift and .sks files and deleting them, cleaning and building the project, replacing the files and then running it. (This has worked for me once in the past when I had the exact same issue) I have heard that deleting the derived data for my project specifically can help with little issues so I went and did that to see if it would help, but it also didn't.

I am clueless as to what to do now and I can't find anything online that specifically gives a solution or a few possible solutions to fix this.

Thank you in advance for any possible solutions

Comment: You know I've had a bug similar to this with SpriteKit before. I can't guarantee that it will help, but I remember it working for me. I had to create a whole new GameScene.swift file - but give it an entirely new name, like "NewGameScene.swift", delete the old one, update the name in the `.sks` file under "Custom Class", and then make sure to tell my GameViewController presents the scene `view.presentScene(scene)`. It's so weird but I couldn't get it working when the file was named `GameScene.swift` just creating a new file with a new name worked for me.

Comment: Which Xcode you use? In Xcode 8 there is no option to delete derived data (other then manually), so you may be using Xcode 7, right? Also have you tried Product -> Clean , and if testing on Simulator, to clear its content and settings?

Comment: Thank you for the responses both of you;

So I have actually done what you said Pierce, Unfortunately it didn't work for me still.

And I am using Xcode 8, I deleted the derived data manually. I also have cleaned it and restarted the simulator, as well as Xcode on multiple occasions

Answer (score 1):

Alright! So I tried something that solved this issue for me.

Similar to Pierce's response, what I did was instead of using the same project and replacing the files with themselves and cleaning the product, what worked for me was just making an entirely new project and using the same GameScene.swift and .sks files.

Although they seemed like the two things wouldn't make a difference when it comes to solving the issue, creating a new project and using the same files was better than using the same files and changing things around on my current one.

I just had to re-replace all my asset-images.

Comment: That's more than a little worrying that this workaround works, but the work within your main project doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you create next to the already existing sks file a new sks for for another device type you need to add the "GameScene" class to the newly created sks file under the tab "Custom Class"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgAiM.png)